# Standalone .NET applications

Tags: c#, .net

I want to make a windows standalone application using a database using triggers and procedures.
I want to install it in multiple machines ,so is it possible that I make only one installer and just run it on other machine and all the database configuration is done using the installer.
Is it possible to run an application on another pc without pre-installing .net framework on it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run a .Net application you will need the .Net Framework (and correct version) installed.

It is standard practice to script one installer to install the .Net Framework, database (unattended install) and your application(s). Make sure the installer works on a vanilla machine and you shouldn't have any problems installing the application on other PCs.

**Edit:**

When you go to deploy your application you will need to create a installer. Visual Studio has a couple of options (out-of-the-box) which are probably the easiest to create MSI's. I would recommend your first installer by a simple MSI.

Open your solution in Visual Studio, click File > Add > New PRoject > Other Project Types > Setup and Deployment > Visual Studio Installer >  setup project and read
[How to create a Setup package by using Visual Studio .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307353).

No doubt you'll have some more questions on this and most can be answered by googling the web, here is a great article with lots of tips for new players making installers: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/winformssetup/thread/717cfce0-3061-400f-9ea3-069f73f3a473

This basic Microsoft installer will cover 99% of what you want to do and I encourage you to read up on [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh45kb66(v=vs.90).aspx). For sophisticated installations (eg with the unattended dB install) I use NSIS and use the Wizard in HW Edit to start the scripts off. HTH.

Comment: I am beginner,what do you mean by scripting installers?

Comment: ok, give me 5 minutes and I'll edit my answer and give you a head start.

Answer (score 1):

[WIX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) is an excellent XML based installer. It has some great tools for executing SQL scripts and installing .net dependencies. Tutorial can be found [here](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/). With SQL scripts [here](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/sql/creating-a-database).

You can even call SQL straight out of WIX. This allows you to write user driven UI Properties into the database:

```
<util:User Id='SQLUser' Name='[SQLUSER]' Password='[SQLPASSWORD]' />

<Component Id='SqlComponent' Guid='YOUR_GUID_HERE' KeyPath='yes'>
        <sql:SqlDatabase Id='SqlDatabase' Database='DatabaseName' User='SQLUser' Server='[SQLSERVER]' CreateOnInstall='yes' DropOnUninstall='no' ContinueOnError='no'>
           <sql:SqlScript Id='CreateDatabaseTables' BinaryKey='CreateDatabaseTables' ExecuteOnInstall='yes' />
           <sql:SqlString Id="AddEntryToTableA" ExecuteOnInstall ="yes" ContinueOnError="no" Sequence="1" SQL="INSERT TableA VALUES (N'[PROPERTY1]', N'[PROPERTY2]', N'[PROPERTY3]')" />
        </sql:SqlDatabase>
</Component>
```